# How to use for loop to read in files and apply functions to each file to give a list of data frames

Tags: r

I have 3 data frames:

```
dataF <- data.frame(year = c(1986, 1987, 1988, 1988, 1999),  Female_ID = c("A1","B1","C1","E1","D1"), Terr = c("TAT", "CAT", "PLU", "GER", "ATT")) 

dataM <- data.frame(year = c(1986, 1986, 1986, 1987, 1987, 1988, 1988, 1988, 1988, 1999, 1999),
Male_ID = c("F1", "G1", "H1", "I1", "J1", "K1", "L1", "M1", "N1", "O1", "P1"), Terr = c("GAT","URS","OPI","INN","WOF","DUG","WAT","YUU","WRF","HUT","RIT")
```

genome: gives you the relatedness for every possible combination of male and females above. It looks something like this:

```
    Male_ID   Female_ID  Pair1  Pair2  relatedness
         F1          A1  F1 A1  A1 F1         0.02
    etc...
```

And I have 4 shape files: lala_d1986_t.shp,  lala_d1987t.shp, lala_d1988_t.shp, lala_d1989_t.shp.

Each of these above shape files gives a map of territories for their given year. For example, the first shape file gives a map for the year 1986.

For each year from 1986 to 1989 I read in its shape file, apply some functions to it to give me a list of neighboring territories for each territory; subset the dataF and dataM for the given year; use the dataF, dataM, and the list of neighboring territories for each territory of that given year to create a data frame that has each female paired up with each of the males that are in the territories surrounding her territory; then I find the relatedness between all those pairs using the genome data frame, then I take the mean relatedness of a female and all her male partners to create a data frame with just the female ID, year, and mean relatedness.

I already have all the functions to do what I want to do above, but I'm having trouble in creating a code that allows me to do all this at once without having to do this manually year by year. Specifically, I'm having trouble reading in the correct shape file for each year.

I've tried:

```
   files <- c(lala_d1986_t.shp,  lala_d1987t.shp, lala_d1988_t.shp, lala_d1989_t.shp)
   listofdfs <- list()
   for(j in c(1986:1989) {
     for(i in length(files)){
       getinfo.shape(paste(files[[i]]))
       FSJShape <- readOGR(paste(files[[i]]))
       FSJShape <- subset(FSJShape, TERRYR!='<NA>')
       listofpositions_year <- gTouches(FSJShape, byid = TRUE, returnDense = FALSE)
       listofneighterr_year <- lapply(listofpositions_year, function(x) FSJShape$TERRYR[x])
       names(listofneighterr_year) <- FSJShape$TERRYR
       listofneighterr_year[] <- lapply(listofneighterr_year, as.character)
       dataF_year <- subset(dataF, year == j)
       dataM_year <- subset(dataM, year == j)
       ...
       final_df
       listofdfs[[j]] <- final_df
     }
   }
```

When I run this, it gives me back an error saying it can't find a certain column name. I've done the codes within the for loops already for each year so I know that these all work. What I believe is the problem is the way I'm using the paste function in the first two lines within the for loops. It's reading all the shape files at once and it uses the last shape file it reads in (the one for 1989) for the rest of the codes.

I am not sure how to solve this. I've already tried googling and I can't find anything that does what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might have a typo in the `i` loop initialisation?

```
for (i in length(files)) {
          ^
```

That will only iterate over the last element in the files vector. If you want to iterate over all of them you could change that to:

```
for (i in 1:length(files)) {
```

Or more efficiently:

```
for (i in seq_along(files)) {
```

Hope that fixes it!